# How to use acronym as new SIunit with acronym and siunitx packages?

Tags: footnotes, siunitx, acronyms

I'm using acronym and siunitx packages and I would like to use an acronym as a SI unit.
Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}

\chapter*{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{LSB}{Least Significant Bit}
\end{acronym}

\begin{document}
The range \SIrange{10}{20}{\ac{LSB}}
\end{document}
```

And what I get is the footnotemark on the word 'LSB' but not the note "Least Significant Bit" at the bottom of the page.

I tried also to `\protect` `\ac` but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `\SIrange{10}{20}\expandafter{\ac{LSB}}` works, but this is not what you want to do, each time

Comment: First thought: `\DeclareSIUnit\LSB{\ac{LSB}}` and `\SIrange{10}{20}{\LSB}` but I have a feeling that the footnote text will be lost if the first appearance is as unit…

Comment: @clemens: That's what I tried -- it's lost

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks. As you said, this is not what I wanted, but it's certainly a fix.

Answer (score 1):

You might try the `footnote` package and its `\savenotes` and `\spewnotes`. It should be noted that the current version of the package is 20+ years old. I'm not aware of significant downsides with the package, though…

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,footnote}
\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{LSB}{Least Significant Bit}
\end{acronym}

\savenotes
The range \SIrange{10}{20}{\ac{LSB}}
\spewnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
This solution also works with `siunitx` versions 3.0, however you need to use its new syntax, i.e.: `\SI` is replaced by `\qty`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,footnote}
\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{LSB}{Least Significant Bit}
\end{acronym}

\savenotes
The range \qtyrange{10}{20}{\ac{LSB}}
\spewnotes

\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.